# Type change support in spark parquet read-write

Tags: apache-spark, schema, parquet

I came across one problem while reading parquet through spark.

One parquet file has been written with field `a` of type `Integer`. Afterwards, reading this file with schema for `a` as `Long` gives exception.

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unimplemented
>   type: LongType    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.readIntBatch(VectorizedColumnReader.java:397)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.readBatch(VectorizedColumnReader.java:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextBatch(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:263)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:106)

I thought this compatible type change is supported. But this is not working.

Code snippet of this:

```scala
val oldSchema = StructType(StructField("a", IntegerType, true) :: Nil)

val df1 = spark.read.schema(oldSchema).json("/path/to/json/data")

df1.write.parquet("/path/to/parquet/data")

val newSchema = StructType(StructField("a", LongType, true) :: Nil)

spark.read.schema(newSchema).parquet("/path/to/parquet/data").show()
```

Any help around this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as parquet is column based storage format for Hadoop so it keeps the datatype of the data also. So while reading the parquet with different datatype even if it's upcasting it’s not handled automatically.

You need to specifically cast the data

```scala
val colarraywithcast = Array(col("eid"),col("did"),col("seal").cast(LongType))
    
df.select(colarraywithcast:_*).printSchema
```

Comment: Yes Chandan. Agreed. But I have multiple parquet files with different schema (but all are compatible). I want to read all of them in one go with superset of schema.

Comment: It worked but primarily I wanted to know whether upcasting is suppoted. You mentioned it's not supported. :)

Comment: I said here upcasting or widening means lower data type to higher datatype I.e your example is upcast and I said it’s not implicit. You need to cast it like I mentioned in the answer